# How to set a daily ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to set a daily ID to my tickets.

Can I tell SQL Server to start every day from 0 and increase? then for tomorrow starts from 0 again?

Please explain your answers.

Comment: not sure what do you mean? what are tickets? and why do you want to start again from 0 on the next day?

Comment: i have tickets. but i want to see the tickets that submit today. and get the an ID form 1 to ...

Comment: I removed `asp.net` tag from your question, that it is not related ;).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you create a procedure on the DB to insert your data, so you will have to do something like

```
declare @newID int
select @newID = max(ID)+1 from table where date=@today
if (@newID is null) then @newID=0
```

and then use the @newID on your query to insert.
I assume you have a date field on your table

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand. Can U Explain?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY CAST(yourDateField as date) 
        ORDER BY yourDateField
    ) - 1 AS newId
FROM 
    yourTable;
```

> [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) is a window function that starts from 1 to count of records ordered by your selected field in `ORDER BY` part and resets based on your selected field in `PARTITION BY` part.
>   Note: When I want date part of a dataTime filed I use `CAST(dateTimeField AS date).

HTH